# Can't checkout an android project in STS 2.9.1 and Subversive on Windows 7

Tags: android, svn, windows-7, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, subversive

### The problem

I have a strange problem with SpringSource Tool Suite 2.9.1 Release and Subversive plugin, running on Windows 7 Home Premium x64. I'm trying to checkout an android project from an SVN repository.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. `File > Import > SVN > Project From SVN`
2. I fill in the path to my repository and check the HEAD revision
3. I click `Finish`
4. The project is found and the default option is `Check out as a project with the name specified`. I leave the name alone Set the Depth field to `Recursively` and again, select the HEAD revision.
5. I click `Finish`
6. A progress bar appears for a second just to show an error message:

   ```
   Checkout operation for 'https://(.....)/Android' failed.
   svn: Cannot create new file 'C:\workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\AppName \.svn\lock': System can not find the path specified
   ```

When I retry and follow the steps from 1 to 6, another dialog appears. It says:

```
This project already exists in the workspace 
or there is a data folder in the checkout destination.
```

It allows me to select a folder to overwrite. When I do that, a similar but different error message is shown. It says:

```
Checkout operation for 'https://(...)/Android' failed.
0x0000000f: The folder 'C:\workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\AppName \.svn' is locked by some external process. Please unlock the folder and try to check out the project again.
```

### What I've tried

First, I opened the SVN Lock view to see if there were any locks created by the IDE. There were none.

I restarted the computer, hoping it would solve the problem of any application locking the file but this does not seem to be the case.

After that, I created a new workspace in a different location and tried to check out the project in there. The result was the same.

Then, I attempted to change the version of SVN Kit. The situation persists in:

1. SVN Kit 1.2.3
2. SVN Kit 1.3.5
3. Native Java HL 1.5.4
4. Native Java HL 1.6.12

I thought that changing permissions to the directories of my workspace was worth giving a try. It didn't do the trick either.

Finally, I checked out the project in a different location, using Tortoise SVN and imported it into my workspace. I could run it (though some build path settings seemed to be missing) but it's not a solution. I can't possibly imagine working on the project simultaneously with a couple of people without the ability to commit/update/view history/resolve conflicts in my IDE.

I was advised to install a separate version of eclipse with its own set of tools and a different workspace for this application alone but it doesn't seem like a good idea. I'd like to keep it all in a single IDE. I'd also prefer to avoid reinstalling the whole thing as I don't feel like configuring all the other tools (mostly spring and android-related) from scratch.

Has anybody seen a situation like this? How can I get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's uncear to me whether this is a subversive problem or an SVN problem.  I would try checking out from the command line (you must install SVN command line tools to do this, but I'd recommend having the tools around as a backup anyway).

Checkout from the command line and then import into STS using File -> Import -> Existing projects into workspace.  Once in the workspace, you can select the project -> Team -> Share project to get svn support on it.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the project and check out again , It must be a problem where u are trying to checkout the project which already exists with same name in the Package Explorer